# Parasitic inductance of relay contacts

Tags: hf, rf-power, transmitter, amplifier, measurement

I need to switch a bank of filters operating on bands from about 2MHz to 30MHz. The parasitic series inductance of the relay contact system will have an effect on the performance of my system. Manufacturers of small encapsulated relays, like this [Omron](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g2rl.pdf) unit, don't specify this parasitic value. Has anyone done so?

Comment: just to get a feeling of which orders of magnitude would be relevant: What are the *intended* inductances / capacitances in that system?

Comment: Certainly under 0.1$\mu$H per relay, Marcus.

Comment: I'd expect something in the region of single-digit nH, but that's just a gut feeling based on experiences of free-hanging wire inductances and a rough guess that we can model the conductors to be ca 1mm wide and ca 50mm long

Comment: (by the way, I'm just now realizing that I always only wondered about stray capacitance of such components, not about the inductivity. Interestingly, the [cheaper RF relays'](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/relays/high-frequency-rf-relays/963?k=rf+relay&k=&pkeyword=rf+relay&sv=0&sf=0&FV=ffe003c3&quantity=3&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25) datasheets don't mention inductivity at all. Some at least mention VSWR for frequency ranges; maybe that helps?)

Comment: oh, and not to forget: this sounds like a cool project! If you have any preliminary schematics or photos to share, I think a lot of the hardwary folks in here would be all ears (or eyes)!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the pointer, Marcus. I need up to 1kW power handling. Strangely, the Schrack "RF" series relays from the same manufacturer have no "RF" specs.

Comment: Write them an email (or call)! https://www.schrack.com has an email contact button on their front page, and maybe they simply have preliminary data that they don't want to make public.